# Debug PHP code with XDebug and VS Code

Tags: debugging

For development I use a local Drupal 7 installation on Xampp under Windows 10. I use Visual Studio Code as IDE and want to debug my PHP code with it. I tried to set that up but can not quite get it working. This is my configuration:

- Xampp installation path: c:\xampp
- PHP: c:\xampp\php (version PHP 7.3.17 64bit)
- Drupal files: c:\xampp\htdocs

php.ini additions:

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = "c:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.9.6-7.3-vc15-x86_64.dll"
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.profiler_append = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "c:\xampp\tmp"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"
xdebug.remote_log = "c:\xampp\tmp\xdebug.txt"
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "c:\xampp\tmp"
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time = 36000
```

VS Code launch config:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9000,
            "runtimeExecutable": "c:\\xampp\\php\\php.exe",
            "pathMappings": {
              "c:\\xampp\\htdocs": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "xdebugSettings": {
              "show_hidden": 1
            }
          }
    ]
}
```

- I downloaded the correct xdebug DLL and put it in:
  c:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.9.6-7.3-vc15-x86_64.dll
- In my Chrome browser I installed the "XDebug Helper" extension.
- In VS Code I installed the XDebug extension and set a few breakpoints in my code.

Then I open my Drupal site in Chrome and hit debug in the XDebug Browser extension.
The breakouts don't get deactivated as "unbound" but the debugger does not stop at any of them either.

What am I missing?

Comment: I don't think you need a runtimeExecutable since php is running as part of a web server configuration. See https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/development-tools/configuring-visual-studio-code#s-configuring-xdebug

Comment: You're right. That line is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my VS Code launch config I had to change the `pathMappings` from this:

```
"c:\\xampp\\htdocs": "${workspaceFolder}"
```

into that:

```
"c:\\xampp\\htdocs\\sites\\all": "${workspaceFolder}"
```